# Using react testing-library to manipulate DOM in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm building some custom dev tools inspired by this [Kent C Dodds post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/make-your-own-dev-tools) and trying to automatically fill in some values for a form I've created.

I have an button that triggers this function where I'm trying fill in an input box. Going off his suggestion to use some utilities from `@testing-library/react` I thought this should be possible.

- Is there something wrong with my code?
- Is this even possible? I tried manipulating the DOM directly, but it's a Material UI input and that was also not behaving as expected.

```js
import { screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

async function FillOutForm() {
    // const user = userEvent.setup(); // tried this on and off but didn't seem to matter

    const uploadButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /upload/i });
    uploadButton.click();

    //await for upload modal to open
    await screen.findByRole('dialog');

    const input = await screen.findByLabelText('Name');
    console.log('input', { input }); //works, it found the value

   
    // userEvent.type(input, 'test'); //freezes, no input filled

    // await user.type(input, 'test'); //freezes, no input filled

    // await act(async () => userEvent.type(await input, 'some text')); //fills in the text, but freezes after and gives an error
   console.log('i never get here?');
}
```

**Edit**: This appears to be specific to styled components or Material UI. When I use a vanilla input, `userEvent.type` seems to work just fine.

**Edit #2**: Here's a repro in stack blitz - at least for some freezing behavior.

Uncomment this line to see some type of infinite loop get kicked off.

```
    // userEvent.click(button) //uncomment to see what causes freeze - some type of infinite loop?
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react18-mui-fsezub?file=App.tsx

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Mister_CK there is no error in the console (or anywhere else). The browser tab literally freezes/hangs and I have to force close it when I try to use any of the `userEvent` lines.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're facing.

Comment: I tried to repro in stack blitz, even bringing in Formik which I'm using in my App. Works in stack blitz as I would expect though. Going to keep digging.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react18-mui-fsezub?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had an infinitely rendering component behind the form I was using. It allowed me to interact fine with the form when typing manually, but chaos ensued when I brought in react testing library.

Turns out this is a completely valid use case/approach and works now after I fixed that infinite loop problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with how you are using the useEvent library try the below code and see if it works or not

```
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

async function FillOutForm() {
const uploadButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /upload/i });
userEvent.click(uploadButton);

// Wait for the upload modal to open, assuming there's a loading indicator 
 or some asynchronous behavior
await screen.findByRole('dialog');

const input = screen.getByLabelText('Name');
console.log('input', { input }); // works, it found the input

// Use userEvent.type to enter text into the input field
userEvent.type(input, 'test');

console.log('I get here!');
}

export default FillOutForm;
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't work, it now freezes on the `userEvent.click(uploadButton)` line

Comment: Sorry I will check once and update thanks for the Update